# Task Python Sockets and Hashlibs

Tags: python, sockets, hash

I have an exercise but i have a problem to send from the client {message, SHA256}. I can't send these two messages separately from the client to the server.

The exercise is:

> Create simple Client-Server communication via Sockets where Client
> will send the message in following form → {
> message,SHA_256_hash_value}. Once the server receives the message it
> will parse it, calculate the SHA_256 hash value of the message part
> and compare it with the received hash. If values are matching it will
> send 'OK' back to Client, else 'Message was compromised'.

---

Attempt salvaged from comment:

```
import socket
import hashlib
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1235))
print("ingrese mensaje")
mensaje = input()
while True:
  mensaje_utf = str.encode(mensaje)
  hash_object = hashlib.sha256(mensaje_utf)
  hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
  s.send(mensaje_utf)
  s.send(str.encode(hex_dig))
  datos = s.recv(1024).decode()
  print(datos)
  mensaje = input()
  s.close()
```

---

Here is the server.py

```
import socket
import hashlib

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1235))
s.listen(5)

conn, address = s.accept()

print("Conexion desde: " + str(address))

while True:
   datos = conn.recv(1024).decode()
   if not datos:
       break
   print(datos)
   conn.send (datos.encode())
   conn.close()
```

The question now is how can I separate the message from: {message, SHA256}

Comment: Could you share a minimal code example of what you have so far and show where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: import socket
import hashlib

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1235))

print("ingrese mensaje")
mensaje = input()


while True:
 mensaje_utf = str.encode(mensaje)
 
 hash_object = hashlib.sha256(mensaje_utf)
 hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
 
 s.send(mensaje_utf)
  
 s.send(str.encode(hex_dig))
 datos = s.recv(1024).decode()
 
 print(datos)
 mensaje = input()
 s.close()

Comment: There is the client but is not complete because i dont finish. I dont know how to continue.

Comment: This guide may help you get up to speed with sockets: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67494653/edit) link right under the post for adding details.

Comment: Please review if the client code looks like you wrote it, as the comment does not preserve indentation. Server part was taken directly from the "answer". Besides the actual problem you are facing it may be worth pointing out that in both snippets sockets are opened outside the loops, and closed inside. The second time the loops run will fail for sure when trying to access the closed sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to send the data in the desired form replacing the send calls like below:

```
import socket
import hashlib 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1235))
print("ingrese mensaje") 

mensaje = input() 

while True: 
    mensaje_utf = str.encode(mensaje)
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256(mensaje_utf) 
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

    message_to_send = "{" + mensaje + "," + hex_dig + "}"
    s.send(str.encode(message_to_send)) 

    datos = s.recv(1024).decode() 
    print(datos) 
    mensaje = input() 
    s.close()
```

Comment: import socket
import hashlib

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)

conn, address = s.accept()

print("Conexion desde: " + str(address))

while True:
 datos = conn.recv(1024).decode()
 if not datos:
  break
 print(datos)
 
 
 conn.send (datos.encode())
 conn.close()

Comment: I have an issue with the server to select the part of message, for example if the server recieve : {hello, 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824} how can I select the part of "hello"?

Comment: It helps readability when you edit your initial question and add your code sections there as code snippets. Then the formatting is not lost. And it is easier for someone who sees the questions for the first time to provide an answer.

Comment: Sorry schilli I'm new on this and my english is not so well, so sorry.

Comment: It’s absolutely fine, no worries. I mean instead of posting your code as a comment, add it to your original question. Then the formatting (like line breaks etc) will not be lost. You can always edit your question to provide more information.